# i want to print first image record form Database if its found and stop the loop

Tags: php

i have two tables in DB, one table have the Detail of person like name, place, country, city etc and 2nd table have multiple images records. in some records of images "images" filed is empty, so i want to print only one image. if the image filed is empty leave that and when the image is found? print it and stop the loop.

Here is my code:

```
 $sno= $resultvenue['Sno'];
 $searchphotolinks = mysql_query("SELECT `Image` FROM `Photos` Where `PersonID`='".$sno."' ORDER BY `Sno` ASC");
 while($linkphoto = mysql_fetch_array($searchphotolinks))
 {

 if($linkphoto['PhotosLink']!="")
 {
 ?>

 <div class="imageplace">
 <a href="http://www.bigvenue.net/singlerecord/?id=<?php echo $sno;
 ?>"><img src="<?php echo $finalfile = $linkphoto['Image']; ?>" /></a>
 </div>
 <?php 
 }
 }
```

Comment: why not use limit 1 in query instead loop ... so you just fetch first image only

Comment: are you looking for "break"? http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Comment: btw your code formatting is very very bad you should see   code   formatted in answer

Comment: NullPoiиteя : i have already tried with LIMIT 1, but its not solved my issue, maybe the first field is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$finalfile = null;
while($linkphoto = mysql_fetch_array($searchphotolinks) && $finalfile != null){
    if($linkphoto['PhotosLink']!=""){
        $finalfile = $linkphoto['Image'];
        echo '<div class="imageplace">';
        echo "<a href=\"http://www.bigvenue.net/singlerecord/?id=\"$sno\">";
        echo "<img src=\"$finalfile\" /></a></div";
    }
}
```

This will stop the loop when you've set the `$finalfile` variable

`break;` would also work at the end of your if, and would be preferable, unless you plan on using $finalfile for something later

Comment: although working solution but i would prefer Limit 1 over this

Comment: Would that work though? What if the first result didn't have a 'PhotosLink'

Comment: Looking at the code PhotosLink will always be empty anyway since he is not selecting it.

Comment: thanx bro: i just add counter veriable and for loop and its working fine :) i past the code in my Answare 2. thnx again